# php images mysql not displaying properly after base64 decode

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to upload images into a mySQL db, then retrieve them into comments. However for some reason the images won't show correctly ( sometimes only parts of it ) so I guess I'm doing something wrong. Help would be appreciated.

## kritiek.php

The form

```
<form action="post_comment.php"  method="POST" id="post-comment" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Reactie plaatsen.</legend>
    <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder=" Naam">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="captcha" id="commentCaptcha" placeholder=" captcha">
    <br>
    <textarea name="comment" cols="50" rows="4" maxlength="999" required placeholder=" Laat een reactie achter.."></textarea>
    <br>
    Profiel Foto: <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add comment">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Fetch comments

```
<section id="comments_section">
    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("Host","Username","Password","Database");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Comments_table";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $img=base64_encode($row['image']);
        $date = $row['date'];
        ?>
        <div class="comment">
            <?php
            echo "<br>" . displayImage($img) . "<br>" . $row['name'] . "<br><br>" . $row['comments'] . "<br><br>" . $date . "<br><br>";
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

    function displayImage(&$link){
        if(!empty($link)){
            return "<img alt=\"Profile Picture\" src=\"data:image/*;charset=utf8;base64, $link \">";
        }
        else
        {
            return "<img src='img/nopicture.jpg'>";
        }

    }

    ?>
</section>
```

## post_comment.php

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("Host","Username","Password","Database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
//assign form to variables
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, strip_tags($_POST["name"]));
$comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, strip_tags($_POST["comment"]));
$comment_length = strlen($comment);
$unix_time = time();
$mySQL_date = date( 'Y-m-d', $unix_time);


// Make sure the user uploaded a file
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) {

    // Temporary file name stored on the server
    $tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    // Read the file
    $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $data = addslashes($data);
    fclose($fp);
}

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Comments_table VALUES('','$name','$comment','$data','$mySQL_date')");
header("location: kritiek.php");

mysql_close($con);
```

## mySQL database

[Screenshot of tables](http://4.1m.yt/Mf3Zcz2TZ.png)
[Screenshot of table content](http://1.1m.yt/IqkdeMjun.png)

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem. Is the image stored correctly in the database (so it's a retrieve/decode problem) or does it not end up correctly in your DB? (Then it's a save/encode problem)

Comment: @AndréSchild So I have to try to decode an image then directly encode again without sending to database?

Comment: At the point before you encode64 it, just save it in a temp folder on disk and compare it to the original file uploaded.

Comment: You are adding slashes before you store the image in the database, but you are not stripping them after reading it (and before encoding it). Could that create issues?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro haha tried it and got marvelous results. [screenshot](http://1.1m.yt/w1naieir7.png) and [screenshot](http://2.1m.yt/_cl3lOdGC.png) became [screenshot](http://2.1m.yt/yR2hNAK4A.png) and [screenshot](http://3.1m.yt/pt9J2wxC8.png)

Comment: That doesn't look right :P

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Found it, should have set the mySQL row to longblob instead blob. However the image dimensions arent right yet :l

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Nevermind, just a stupid small mistake, forgot I set the max-width and max-height in stylesheet for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem of it loading improperly, the problem was the mySQL row was set to blob instead longblob, all images had a max size of exact 63.9 kb so it was obvious what was wrong.